# Performing bulk update operation: incrementing an object property inside of an array based on existence of name within the array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am assembling a tags collection where I need to perform an update operation with upsert enabled.

**Edit The function I call to add to tags to the collection is passed a tags array that contains the tags the user entered, the name of a category where the tag has been used, and the actual title of the entry.

The name of the category is important since I want to be able to record how many submissions from users that use the same tag also use the same category which is why I have an entries variable that should increment whenever I add a tag that already has that specific category. This array is named categories and has objects, every object in this array has a categoryName property and the amount of entries that use the same category for this specific tag. I also have an array of the title of the entries of users, this array contains strings.

```
function updateTags(tags, name, simpleString)
{
     var bulk = myModel.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

     for(var t = 0; t < tags.length, t++)
{

//important bit..

  bulk.find({tag : tags[t]}).upsert().update({ //Query to update document views or a new object to the categories array  })
}

bulk.execute(cb);

}
```

Here is a sort of algorithmic approach that the query should perform.

-check for the existence of a tag

--if a tag exists check if any categoryName properties from the entries within the categories array match the category name passed into the function

---if that specific categoryName already exists within the array, increment its entries by one.

--if the categoryName does not exist add an object with the properties categoryName set to the name passed to the function and set its entries to one.

regardless of the previous existence of categoryName within categories array, add the title (a string) to the array of title entries.

-if the tag does not exist add a document with the tag, a categories array with a single object that has catagoryName set to the category name passed and its entries set to one. Also add the title to the array of title properties.

Comment: This still comes out a bit "jumbled" to me after several reads. Why is "tags" being iterated here and where is the data that is supposed to be going into "categories" coming from? Also what is "simpleString"? A "constant" value or something else?  Which array? "categories"? So I think your question would be clearer if you addressed these "questions" with an edit.

Comment: Alright I have revised and hopefully made it clearer. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are basically correct in that these are "Bulk" operations because you need "more than one" update statement here:

```js
function updateTags(tags,name,title,callback) {
    var bulk = myModel.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

   tags.forEach(function(tag) {

       // Update where the category does exist
       bulk.find({ 
           "tag": tag,
           "categories.name": name
       }).updateOne({
           "$inc": { "categories.$.count": 1 },
           "$addToSet": { "titles": title }
       });

       // Push where the category does not exist           
       bulk.find({ 
           "tag": tag, 
           "categories.name": { "$ne": name } 
       }).updateOne({
           "$push": { "categories": { "name": name, "count": 1 } },
           "$addToSet": { "titles": title }
       });

       // Upsert where the tag was not found, but do nothing else
       // Other than add the title to the set
       bulk.find({ "tag": tag }).upsert().updateOne({
           "$setOnInsert": {
               "categories": [{ "name": name, "count": 1 }],
               "titles": [title]
           },
       });

   });

   bulk.execute(callback);
}
```

So what that is going to do for "each" tag, is construct three different requests to the server. The conditions are set so that of each of those requests only "one" will actually match a document and modify it.

Actually there will possibly be "two" matches per set, but only "one" of them can make any modifications. This is because [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) does not apply to a "matched" document with an "upsert" operation. So that operation does "nothing" unless the "tag" was not matched and a new document is created.

Once all requests for each tag have been built you will send to the server and receive the response. The modified count in the response will always be equal to the number of "tags" sent in as the argument.

Comment: This works flawlessly, I appreciate your assistance. I guess my sin was trying to cram the entire procedure onto a single statement. Thanks.